# Yield in Python needs to be implemented in java

Tags: java, yield, yield-return

I have a following question:

Write a class that takes a series of integers from a generator that generates numbers one by one. Include two functions: 1- Sum 2- Average.

I know that yield statement is the choice in python if the generator needs to generate numbers one by one by returning at each step.

How would you guys do it in java? I somehow don't have any idea of how I can realize this

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Using a simple for-loop should work? Or are you looking something more concise?

Comment: Can you please show it how simple for loop would look like? Please be sure that the numbers generated only one by one from a generator.

Comment: If this is homework, it should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to implement "sequence" like behavior you may choose to implement java.util.Iterator interface.

```
class RandomSequence implements Iterator<Integer>, Iterable<Integer> {
     private int count;
     private Random random;


     public RandomSequence(int count) {
        this.count = count;
        this.random = new Random();
     }

     Integer next() {
        count--;

        return random.nextInt();

     }

     boolean hasNext() {
        return count > 0;
     }

     Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return this;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         int n = 0;
         for(int n: new RandomSequence(10))
             sum += n;
     }

}
```

Comment: Hi aav, your code is not working. In java, for(int n: new RandomSequence(10)) is not allowed, it can only iterate over an array or instance of iterable.

Comment: ups. sorry - my fault. it has to be Iterable - i will update the example now.